# How to translate !title field is required

Tags: i18n-l10n

I want to translate '!title field is required.'.
I can see it in 'admin/config/regional/translate/translate' but if I put a translation, it will override the name/label of each field.

So it is taking '!title field is required.' as one string. But I just want to translate 'field is required' and field names separately.

For example a Name and Email required in a form should display same translation but replacing !title with the name of the field.

How to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To change the field name, you have to translate `!name field is required.` . To do this, follow these following steps :

1. Go to `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`.
2. Search for the string `!name field is required` in the `String contains` textfield.
3. In search result, change the string for all the languages.
4. And then save it.

I hope it works.